# C: store tokens in growing array

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic, malloc

I am currently learning C and want to write a program that reads a line of numbers (from a file), seperated by spaces (for example: 43 2 6 120 5 23), and then stores those numbers in a dynamic array.
My idea so far is to read the line as a string, seperate it into tokens *(strtok)*, then convert those tokens to int numbers *(atoi)* and store those.
My problem is that I have to allocate memory using *malloc*, but can’t tell the program how much memory is needed manually, because it has to be able to work with lines of any length and numbers of any size, and I don’t know how to do that. I am *not* supposed to use *realloc*.

I don’t want anyone to do my work for me, just a simple example and/or good explanation of a way to do what I want would be really helpful. If anymore information is needed, I’ll give it to you.
I know that there are some questions on this topic on here and I have looked at them, I just have a hard time understanding some things without having them explained, since I’m completely new to C programming.
Of course, if anyone can give me a link that might help me, that would be great as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a separate function that will extract numbers from a string and store them in a dynamically allocated array without using `realloc`.
To count the numbers in the string before allocating the array you can use standard C function `sscanf`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t get_data( const char *s, int **a )
{    
    int x;
    size_t n;
    int m;

    *a = NULL;
    n = 0;

    for ( const char *p = s; sscanf( p, "%d%n", &x, &m ) == 1; p += m ) ++n;

    if ( n && ( *a = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) ) ) )
    {
        const char *p = s;
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++, p += m ) sscanf( p, "%d%n", *a + i, &m );
    }

    return n;
}    

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = " 43 2 6 120 5 23";
    int *a;
    size_t n = get_data( s, &a );

    if ( n )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }        

    free( a );
}
```

The program output is

```
43 2 6 120 5 23
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped me understand things better. But would you, or anyone, mind explaining the counting part a little more thoroughly?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty standard application for the use of dynamic memory. What you will do is declare memory for an initial number of integers, read until you reach that number, reallocate your array twice as big as it was, and keep going until you have read all of your data.

While reading an entire line of data into a buffer and then parsing the buffer for what you need is generally the best practice, in this case `fscanf` was tailor made to handle the reading and conversion of a single integer value (and it will automatically consume the whitespace separating the values).

(`calloc` is used below to initialize all element to `0`, `malloc` is fine in this example, but initializing prevents an inadvertent read from an uninitialized element in more complex situations)

Here is a short example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXI 64

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int *array = NULL;
    size_t idx = 0, max_idx = 0;
    size_t arraysize = MAXI;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed. '%s'\n", argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin");
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate initial array */
    array = calloc (MAXI, sizeof *array);

    /* read values from file */
    while (fscanf (fp, "%d", &array[idx]) == 1) {
        idx++;

        /* realloc if necessary */
        if (idx == arraysize) {
            int *tmp = realloc (array, arraysize * sizeof *array * 2);
            if (!tmp) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc - virtual memory exhausted.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            array = tmp;
            memset (array + arraysize, 0, arraysize);  /* zero new memory */
            arraysize *= 2;
        }
    }

    /* close file */
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    max_idx = idx;

    /* print array */
    for (idx = 0; idx < max_idx; idx++)
        printf (" array[%3zu] : %d\n", idx, array[idx]);

    free (array);   /* free memory */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Data**

```
$ cat dat/100intspace.txt
27086 29317 32736 3356 12059 13921 9388 25672 19828 25390 -1190 25857 ...
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_dyn_read_int dat/100intspace.txt
 array[  0] : 27086
 array[  1] : 29317
 array[  2] : 32736
 array[  3] : 3356
 array[  4] : 12059
 array[  5] : 13921
 array[  6] : 9388
 array[  7] : 25672
 array[  8] : 19828
 array[  9] : 25390
 array[ 10] : -1190
 array[ 11] : 25857
 ...
```

**Validate Your Memory Use**

Whenever you are allocating memory dynamically, it is your responsibility to (1) keep track of what you allocate; (2) preserve a pointer to the starting address (so you can free it later); and (3) freeing the memory when it is no longer needed. `valgrind` or a similar memory error checker are simple to use and should be used to validate your memory use:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/array_dyn_read_int dat/100intspace.txt
==7348== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7348== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7348== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7348== Command: ./bin/array_dyn_read_int dat/100intspace.txt
==7348==
 array[  0] : 27086
 array[  1] : 29317
 array[  2] : 32736
 array[  3] : 3356
 array[  4] : 12059
 array[  5] : 13921
 array[  6] : 9388
 array[  7] : 25672
 array[  8] : 19828
 array[  9] : 25390
 array[ 10] : -1190
 array[ 11] : 25857
 ....
==7348==
==7348== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7348==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7348==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 1,336 bytes allocated
==7348==
==7348== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7348==
==7348== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7348== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind about consecutive white-spaces, then you could simply count the number of them and add one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[] = "43 2 6 120 5 23";

    size_t numCount = 1;
    char *ptr = line;
    while (*ptr != '\0') {
        if (*ptr == ' ') {
            numCount++;
        }
        ptr++;
    }

    // malloc call, etc.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading a line, the code will need to scan the line twice, once to count the numbers (so that the correct amount of memory can be allocated), and again to convert the numbers and store them in the array.

The problem with using `strtok` is that it will modify the line, which prevents the code from using `strtok` to scan the line a second time.

So the solution is to write a simple `for` loop that parses the line and counts the numbers. To do this, you need a variable that keeps track of whether you're inside a number or between numbers. Here's the pseudocode:

```
state = outside
count = 0
for each character in the line
    if ( state == outside )
    {
        if ( isdigit(character) )
            count++
            state = inside
    }
    else
    {
        if ( isspace(character) )
            state = outside
    }
```

At the end of the loop, `count` can be used to allocate memory for the array, and then you can use `strtok` and `strtol` to convert the numbers. Note that I've left out error checking for the case where a character is neither a digit nor whitespace.